# The method loadUrl(String) is undefined for the type Activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap. And read it and created my work.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

And i added this line in MyworkActivity.java:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

But when run as my project, get this error:

```
The method loadUrl(String) is undefined for the type Activity
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Is the error when you try and run the app or is it compile time error (you see a red x error icon in your source code)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you are using `PhoneGap`, Your class is extended with `DroidGap` instead of `Activity`, so please check you have probably extended your class `Activity`.